# Finding Views not in the current view

Tags: android, view

I am currently trying to implement a `ViewPager`. I have two pages within the ViewPager which both contain numerous text fields, checkboxes, buttons, and spinners.

Lets say the two XML files are `layout1.xml` and `layout2.xml`. Both of them have checkboxes with the IDs `checkbox1` and `checkbox2` respectively. Is there a way to call something along the lines of

```
 Checkbox check1 = (CheckBox) findViewById( R.layout.layout1.id.checkbox1 );
 Checkbox check2 = (Checkbox) findViewById( R.layout.layout2.id.checkbox2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the best way to do this was to use a `LayoutInflater`. [`Look at this question for reference`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221986/how-can-i-reference-layout-files-other-than-the-current-one)

Answer (score 1):

The `View` class has a `findViewById` method which allows you to find views that are children of only that view. If you get a reference to each page's `View` container, you can get each respective `CheckBox`:

```
CheckBox check1 = (CheckBox) view1.findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
CheckBox check2 = (CheckBox) view2.findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
```

Comment: OK, thanks. I have tried `analogView = (View) findViewById( R.layout.analogs );`, then called `doButton = (Button) analogView.findViewById( R.id.doButton );` But I get a null pointer exception when trying to intialize the button. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: I also tried setting the layout files id to `analogView` and calling `analogView = (View) findViewById( R.id.analogView );`