# How can I reference layout files other than the current one?

Tags: android, android-layout, view

In my application I call `setContentView( layout1.xml );`, I want to access an element within a DIFFERENT layout file, lets call it layout2.xml.

I have tried

```
view1 = (View) findViewById( R.layout.layout2 );
```

and also added an id to the layout and tried

```
view1 = (View) findViewById( r.id.layout2 );
```

Neither of these work. They compile just fine but when I run it, as soon as i try to call something like

```
button1 = view1.findViewById( R.id.button1 );
```

I get a null pointer exception.

Comment: Need more details on what you are trying to accomplish.  The xml file only defines the structure of the `View`, but it is only instantiated as a real object after it has been inflated (via `setContentView` or `LayoutInflator`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a layout inflater to get your second layout like so:

```
 View view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout2, null);
```

And then reference your button from that layout:

```
Button button1 = view.findViewById( R.id.button1 );
```

Comment: Do I need to install a special package to get `LayoutInflator`? After trying that it gives me an error and when I hover over the text there is no `import ...` option.

Comment: Hah. Note there are other ways to get the inflater. If you need control of the inflater via an object you can instantiate it via: mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  Then call mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2, this, false);

Answer (score 2):

You can access an element from layout2 by inflating it first as follows:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2, null);
    //or View view = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2, null);
    Button button = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    //add code for button
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider looking [HERE](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html). You can create layouts and reuse them in different layouts by using `include` in the XML